# How should I calculate the p-value for a bootstrapped Pearson correlation?

Tags: correlation, p-value, bootstrap, pearson-r

Should I look up the $p$-value using a $z$ score from the mean of bootstrapped correlation coefficient estimates ($r$) and the standard error of those estimates ($SE$)?
$$
z = 0.5 \ln\left(\frac{1+r}{1-r}\right)/SE
$$

Or should I use a $t$ score?
$$
t = r \sqrt{\frac{N-2}{1-r^2}}
$$
(In this case, would $N$ be from the original sample? Or do the bootstrap replicates somehow change the number used for $N$?)

Or should I somehow use the bootstrap confidence intervals (e.g., bootstrap-t CI or BCa CI)?

Or do I use the $p$-value from the original (non-bootstrapped) correlation?